# how grails 3.0.x create custom war name with different file suffix

Tags: grails, gradle

In grails 3.0.(1,2,3) the `war` file exist under the folder 'build/libs'

However, I want to rename the war name with different file suffix, like "app.tar.gz", without the version.

the google result is all about grails 2.x

I put the `grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}.tar.gz"` in the file `application.groovy` under the folder conf but it's useless.

Plz help me, i googled and try to find solution in the source code `BuildSettings.groovy`, but the it's no use.

Comment: when applying the Spring Boot Gradle plugin together with war plugin -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/54502456/5308115

Answer (score 2):

As of grails version 3, the build tool is gradle, you would need to change those parameters from your build.gradle file

If you do not want the version as part of your package name, you will need to comment (or remove) the version from build.gradle file

for example, running the following

```
fhenri@machine:~/project/grails/sample307$ grails -version
| Grails Version: 3.0.7
| Groovy Version: 2.4.4
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_51
fhenri@machine:~/project/grails/sample307$ grails package
...
fhenri@machine:~/project/grails/sample307$ find . -name *.war
./build/libs/sample-0.1.war

After you remove the version from `build.gradle` file
fhenri@machine:~/project/grails/sample307$ grails package
...
fhenri@machine:~/project/grails/sample307$ find . -name *.war
./build/libs/sample.war
```

Grails uses the [war gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html), from the plugin the pattern to make the archive name is `[baseName]-[appendix]-[version]-[classifier].[extension]`, the version already comes from the `build.gradle` file as generated from `grails create-app`

each of this can be overwritten in a war closure, for example, an excerpt of the build.gradle could be

```
version "0.1"
war {
  appendix "so-test"
  version "1.0"
}
```

The generated war file will be `sample-so-test-1.0.war` the version will come from the war closure.

So if you want to keep the mail `version` properties but do not want to generate the version in your generated war name you can overwritten the property with an empty value

```
version "0.1"
war {
  version ""
}
```

will generate a war file without the version information, but still you could keep it for you if you want to use it somewhere else.

To package as tar/zip, you can
follow the documentation for grails 3: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/deployment.html (chapter on TAR/ZIP distribution)

Comment: The war file name doesn't appear to be configurable from within build.gradle. Appears to use a "war" plugin. The war task seems to be available magically and doesn't appear to take any configuration parameters.

Comment: @Michael the gradle war plugin does not take any configuration parameters ? no it takes plenty, see [gradle doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html) the `archivename` is what ultimately makes the war file name which by default is `[baseName]-[appendix]-[version]-[classifier].[extension]` and version is coming from the properties too. I did not test latest grails version 3.1 but for 3.0.x it was just using the war task as defined by gradle doc and worked as expected

Comment: @Michael re-run all the samples I made on grails 3.1.9 still working the same so not sure what you mean by _The war file name doesn't appear to be configurable from within build.gradle_ version from war file is from the default `version` from file after grails generate it and everything else can be configured through the war closure

Comment: I finally figured out I could add a war closure to override settings and I found the page  you linked to that had the available properties. That isn't readily intuitive if you don't know anything about Gradle. However, it makes sense now since I spent some time with it.

Comment: @Michael true but now grails uses gradle if you need advanced build feature you'd need to turn on gradle, good thing is that there is good documentation and good community

Comment: Yes, my issue was caused by an ignorance of Gradle, I am coming up to speed on it it though.

Answer (score 1):

In build.gradle, after applying the gradle war plugin you can do this:

```
war {
   archiveName = "ROOT.war"
}
```

And a ROOT.war file will be created at build/libs