# Gradle 'war' plugin how to change name of an archive

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, war

How can I change the name of war?

I already tried (I found these params in documentation https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html)

```
war {
baseName = 'service'
archiveName 'service.war'
}
```

However, this is not working. I am still getting a name with a snapshot version.

```
./build/libs/search-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

I am using Gradle 4.10 and Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please refer to this documentation : [Spring Boot Gradle reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#reacting-to-other-plugins-war)

To sum up: when applying the Spring Boot gradle plugin together with `war` plugin, the `war` task is disabled by default and "replaced" by the SpringBoot `bootWar` task.

So if you want to configure the war artefact, you will need to configure the `bootWar` task instead of base `war` task :

```
bootWar {
    baseName = 'service'
    archiveName 'service.war'
}
```

Additional notes:

- in Gradle 5.x , `archiveName` has been deprecated, and you should use `archiveFileName` instead
- if you set the `archiveName` property you don't need to set `baseName` property

Answer (score 8):

M. Ricciuti answer is correct, with the caveat that even though `archiveName` has been deprecated in Gradle 5.x, Spring Boot is still using it in 2.1.6.RELEASE. For example, if the **bootWar** task was configured with the new `archiveFileName` property like this:

```
bootWar {
    archiveFileName 'service.war'
}
```

you will get this error:

> Could not find method archiveFileName() for arguments [service.war] on task ':bootWar' of type org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootWar.

Use `archiveName` for now. See Spring [BootWar class Java doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/api/org/springframework/boot/gradle/tasks/bundling/BootWar.html) for details. They may add `archiveFileName` in the future.

Answer (score 5):

```
bootWar {
    archiveFileName.set 'service.war'
}
```

Comment: It's the only syntax working with Gradle >= 8.0, good job.

Answer (score 2):

codemule - answer is correct, with a different error message when `archiveFileName` was used in `bootWar` task. I am using Gradle 6.5.1.

With the below bootWar task

```
bootWar {
    archiveFileName 'bst.war'
}
```

I got the error message

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'example'.
> No signature of method: build_1z1dezuc71i4g9wsz51um0q6o.bootWar() is applicable for argument types: (build_1z1dezuc71i4g9wsz51um0q6o$_run_closure1) values: [build_1z1dezuc71i4g9wsz51um0q6o$_run_closure1@7abe6e]
```

It disappeared when bootWar task was configured with archiveName

```
bootWar {
    archiveName 'example.war'
}
```

Comment: archiveFileName is a property whereas archiveName is a string, rather use TMRnoMEM's answer. The first syntax you used has no chance to work.

Answer (score 0):

If one want to change the name of the archive dynamically, use system property with a default in either:

```scala
bootWar {
    archiveFileName.set project.getProperty('warName') ?: 'service.war'
}
```

or

```java
bootWar {
    archiveName project.getProperty('warName') ?: 'service.war'
}
```

then it's possible to customize the war file name using:

```bash
./gradlew -PwarName=<custom_name>.war bootWar
```